# Installing the ADT Plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I am having trouble installing the plugin, I have tried with and without https, http ect. I have downloaded the file and tried to install it that way.

Everytime the green bar at the bottom just doesn't move and then after about 10 mins i get this message.

```
Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/drops/R3.3.2/R-3.3.2-20120210195245/repository/content.jar.
Read timed out
```

Im using windows 7 and eclipse indigo.
Any ideas, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that the repository is down for some time or your firewall blocks your connection with the repository.

Either way: read and apply "Troubleshooting ADT Installation" section of http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

In summary: you can always download the plugin and install it manually (by copying to a right folder).

Good luck!

Edit: how to install the plugin manually? The instruction is [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) again at section "Troubleshooting ADT Installation". If you happen to be too lazy to find the section, I copied the most relevant part for you:

- Download the current ADT Plugin zip file from the table below (do not unpack it).
- Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....
- Click Add, in the top-right corner.
- In the Add Site dialog, click Archive.
- Browse and select the downloaded zip file.
- Enter a name for the local update site (e.g., "Android Plugin") in the "Name" field.
- Click OK.
- In the Available Software dialog, select the checkbox next to Developer Tools and click Next.
- In the next window, you'll see a list of the tools to be downloaded. Click Next.
- Read and accept the license agreements, then click Finish.
  *Note:* If you get a security warning saying that the authenticity or validity of the software can't be established, click OK.
- When the installation completes, restart Eclipse

Comment: or how to stop the firewall blocking it? I also tried to view the marketplace through eclipse andhad the same problem, the green bar just stopped moving for 10 mins...