# Can't open .java files

Tags: java, android, eclipse, aptana

I'm using Aptana studio 3 and I installed the 'Eclipse Java Development Tools' but when i try and open .java files in Aptana i get this message,

```
Could not write metadata for 'C:/ ....
```

However in the package explorer it can see inside the file, It has the

```
onCreate(Bundle):void
```

which i assume is some sort of function that the project creates for you.
I'm new to android development but not coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to android development I suggest using eclipse with the ADT this adds extra tools to eclipse for android development.
see [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/adding-components.html) for a how to.

Comment: I tried using eclipse origionaly but had even bigger problems, I couln't install any updates or tools, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10644539/installing-the-adt-plugin

Comment: are you behind a proxy or something

Comment: they may have a proxy, but you should verify to know for sure. And maybe they can help you.

Comment: Use Eclipse for Java EE instead of the standard one.